# Sequelize inner join between 2 tables from 2 different databases

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

I'm currently trying to do an inner join between two tables:
The first one is in a database called `SmartMonument` while the second one is in a database called `SmartMonumentCB`.

Here is the code for the init of those table:

In 'database.js' (referring to `SmartMonument`):

```
const CompaniesForClient=sequelize.define('cfc', {
    scrapperName: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
    clientID: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER(10), allowNull: false}
});

CompaniesForClient.sync();
module.exports = { sequelize, CompaniesForClient };
```

The second table is :

```
const Companies = sequelize.define('companies', {
    scrapperName: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
    scrapperAddress: {type: Sequelize.STRING(500)}
});
Companies.sync();
module.exports = {sequelize, Companies};
```

Both tables are well created and then I try to add something so both tables are related on the `scrapperName` field.

I try to do it like such:

```
CompaniesForClient.hasOne(CompaniesDB.Companies, {foreignKey: 'scrapperName'});
```

My goal is ultimatly to be able to read all the `CompaniesForClient` fields with all the fields of `Companies` in one request like such:

```
CompaniesForClient.findAll({where:{clientID: param}, include: [{model: Companies}];
```

Right now I get the following error :

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Cannot add foreign key constraint
    at Query.formatError(/home/ubuntu/backendDev/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:222:16)
    at Query.connection.query [as onResult] (/home/ubuntu/backendDev/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:55:23)
    at Query.Command.execute (/home/ubuntu/backendDev/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:30:12)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/backendDev/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:515:28)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/ubuntu/backendDev/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:94:16)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/ubuntu/backendDev/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:77:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/backendDev/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:102:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:253:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:211:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:585:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your foreign key (if not primary) is unique and also check if the data in your database is matching with the data from the table that you are going to associate it with (of course in the foreign key column)